# How to activate Azur active directory login for separate .Net core 5 API and Blazor App?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I am very new to Blazor app. But I develop a .Net core 5 API for accessing and manipulating database. I also have a Client-side Blazor App that is consuming API and acting as a frontend. These two projects are completely separated and running on a different thread like https://localhost:44397/ for API and
https://localhost:7140/ Blazor App.

At present The authentication and authorization have been done with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer

Where Blazor app is sending Login Model and getting JWT for internal roles and data calling.

My Idea is not clear how I can connect these two instances with azure active directory login so that I don't have to save user registration data for API users. I have seen so many articles but all they have is Blazor web assembly where server and SPA are in the same project.
Any leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the workaround which may help to authenticate your Blazor and .net core api with Azure AD separately.

Firstly, You will need to register an application for authenticate our application with Azure AD and have to get the details, to provide in your `app.settings.json` for both of the application.

For example:-

```
"AzureAd": {  
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",  
    "Domain": "*Your domain name*", //Domain name configured in Azure  
    "TenantId": "0000-00000-00000-0000", // Tenant Id configured in Azure  
    "ClientId": "0000-00000-00000-0000", //  Client Id configured in Azure  
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
```

For complete setup please refer this [***Blog to Add authenticate your `.net core web API` with Azure AD***](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-azure-ad-authentication-using-net-5-0-web-api/).

To do the same with Blazor app, Once the app registration is done you will have to add the similar in your `appsettigs.json`

For example:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "{DOMAIN}",
    "TenantId": "{TENANT ID}",
    "ClientId": "{SERVER API APP CLIENT ID}",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
}
```

For complete setup with Blazor Application please refer this ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:*** [***Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly hosted app with Azure Active Directory***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

For more information please refer this SO THREAD:- [***ASP.NET Core Web API + Azure AD Authentication***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57033874/asp-net-core-web-api-azure-ad-authentication)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AjayKumarGhose-MT. Yes I will try

Comment: Glad to be of help!